# Use Java Pattern to extract word between HTML tag with attributes

Tags: java, html, regex

I am using the java Pattern & Matcher to extract the words between two tags.

My code is like:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<([A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*)\\b[^>]*>(.*?)</\\1>");
    List<String> topicArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("<City count='1' relevance='0.304' normalized='Shanghai,China'>Shanghai</City>");
    while (matcher.find()) {
        topicArray.add(matcher.group(1));
    }
```

The system only gives me City as output instead of Shanghai. What's wrong with it?

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/1065197

Comment: Use an HTML parsing library, that is what they are meant for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the next:

```
private static final Pattern REGEX_PATTERN = 
        Pattern.compile("<[^>]*>([^<>]*)<[^>]*>");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "<City count='1' relevance='0.304' normalized='Shanghai,China'>Shanghai</City>";

    System.out.println(
        REGEX_PATTERN.matcher(input).replaceAll("$1")
    );  // prints "Shanghai"
}
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Is there a way to check the tags within a tag? E.g. <City count....><Name id="cccc">Shanghai</Name></City>